# Squid on Linux being detected as proxy, but not on Windows

Tags: debian, proxy, squid

I have added the following to my squid.conf

```
#Privacy Things
via off
forwarded_for off
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
```

but when I go to whoer.net it can detect that I am going through a proxy, and the way it detects it, is by seeing that port 3128 is cached. This does not happen with Squid on Windows. How can I fix this problem? I'm running Squid on Debian 9

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Open port" means that your service is available from the internet.

Please consider using a firewall like iptables on linux so that the proxy is no longer available.

The "cached" is only the information that the open port was detected earlier, it has nothing to do how you connect to the internet! This is an open port which means that anyone on the world can at least connect to this port. You can always hope for the service (squid) to deny access from there, but it's much safer to simply block the port.